# Xcode Keyboard Shortcuts Conflicted

Tags: xcode, keyboard

Xcode has a preferences window that allows you to set keyboard shortcuts
but many of my shortcuts are conflicted. [image: Xcode shortcuts]

I've looked through all of system preferences for anything using these key combinations and came up with nothing and I closed down all third party apps like Alfred and still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I hit this batch of conflicts recently. I don't remember where I found them, but it did turn out that Xcode was correct. Hopefully, someone remembers where. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem too, and nothing in Keyboard Shortcuts in System Preferences was showing "^-6" as bound to anything.  But I figured it out...

- Activate Mission Control
- Add a bunch of spaces (I added 5, so I had 6 total [not counting Dashboard])
- Go back to Keyboard Shortcuts. You should now see the "Switch to Desktop *n*" options there under the Mission Control heading
- Uncheck them
- Reactivate Mission Control and remove the added spaces

Comment: Thanks David, I also figured it out the same way about 15 minutes after I asked. Can you go tell whoever worked on the Snow Leopard import, that they almost had me pulling my hair out :)?

Answer (score 0):

- The control + function keys are found in Keyboard Shortcuts, in the section on moving keyboard selection around. Things like **Move focus to Dock**. (I forget what it's called, maybe Keyboard & Text?)
- Command-option 8 is Accessibility, for **Turn zoom on and off**. I'm not sure where command-option-\ is found.
- The control-# keys are probably Spaces/Mission Control shortcuts. I think they're control + number by default. How to configure these has shifted around a little.