# What are alternative keyboard shortcuts for Mission Control if you use Xcode?

Tags: keyboard, xcode, mission-control

As listed in this question [Xcode Keyboard Shortcuts Conflicted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47772/xcode-keyboard-shortcuts-conflicted) there are a lot of Mission Control shortcuts that interfere with Xcode and I was wondering what are some good alternative keyboard shortcuts for Mission Control that don't interfere with Xcode or any other major apps.

Comment: if you go to `System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts` you can define your own shortcut for mission control.

Comment: @RossMcKinley Right. I know how, I need suggestions on what. Thanks for your comment as it will help others who don't know how.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake! It's largely situation specific, since it depends on which apps you use most frequently, and whether you need mission control easily accessible in all of those apps. You could try `alt+ctrl+up`, and then change it again the next time it conflicts.

Comment: @RossMcKinley Thanks, I'll try that. I also need suggestions on switching spaces left, right, and switching to a specific space (1-8?).